# Cannot find correct button ID using Selenium

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

I am trying to get Selenium to press the button called 'Episodes' at the referenced URL below. However I am getting an error saying that it cannot find the button ID I am feeding it...

Code:

```
import sys
from selenium import webdriver


sys.path.append("G:\\Python27\\mypath")


class button_press():

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://www.sky.com/new-search/chernobyl?q=chernobyl")
    button = driver.find_element_by_id('tabs-id_2474-link-1')
    button.click()

    print driver.content
```

Object source code from Chrome Developer Tools:

```
<button role="tab" type="button" id="tabs-id_2474-link-1" class="c-tabs__link" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tabs-id_2474-article-1" data-test-id="episodes-tab-button">Episodes</button>
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/cg371/Downloads/Selenium)Test.py", line 8, in <module>
    class button_press():
  File "C:/Users/cg371/Downloads/Selenium)Test.py", line 12, in button_press
    button = driver.find_element_by_id('tabs-id_2474-link-1')
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 360, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="tabs-id_2474-link-1"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.108)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using xpath, you will get your result.

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div/div/div/div/section/section/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[2]/button")
```

[Resulted image after using xpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUWQA.png)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try using the xpath?

button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div/div/div/div/section/section/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[2]/button')

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

xpath:-

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(.,'Episodes')]");
```

Also try this:-

```
button =driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[2]/button");
```

For finding correct path of that element you can use selenium ide which is extension in mozilla

check below image:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tyr this..

```
This is xpath using button id.

button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='tabs-id_2474-link-1']")
```